# Coloring $5 \times5$ transparent chessboard in space.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, permutation-cycles

> We have $5 \times 5$ chessboard floating in space , so rotation and reflection are allowed. We want to color it using $m$ distinct colors such that when we color a square , the both sides of that square will be colored , so the both faces of chess board will be coloring while we are coloring one face. (You may think that this chessboard is transparent ) How many nonequivalent coloring are there ?

**My work:**

- $\psi(\pi_0^*)=m^{25}$ , the identity permutation.
- $\psi(\pi_1^*)=m^{7}$ , $90$ degree rotation.
- $\psi(\pi_2^*)=m^{13}$ , $180$ degree rotation.
- $\psi(\pi_3^*)=m^{7}$ , $270$ degree rotation.
- $\psi(r_1^*)=m^{15}$ , horizontal reflection.
- $\psi(r_2^*)=m^{15}$ , vertical reflection.
- $\psi(r_3^*)=m^{15}$ , diagonal reflection (positive slope diagonal).
- $\psi(r_4^*)=m^{15}$ , diagonal reflection (negative slope diagonal).

$$\frac{1}{4}(m^{25}+2m^7 +m^{13} +4m^{15})$$

Is my solution correct ?

**EDITED ANSWER:** $$\frac{1}{8}(m^{25}+2m^7 +m^{13} +4m^{15})$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. Remember, there are $8$ possible transformations, so you need $\frac18$ in front, not $\frac14$. (As a quick check, what should the answer be if there is only a single color available, i.e. $m = 1$?)

Apart from that, I agree with all your calculations, and also with your decision to go with [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma).

Comment: yes , what a silly mistake .))